# Make eclipse save an XML file after undoing all its changes?

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, undo, revert

Assuming I have just opened a `file.xml` in eclipse and then made a single change to it, the title bar for this file shows that I just made a change `*file.xml`. The problem is that once I undo that change (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>), the file stays in the dirty state.

Is it possible to get eclipse to autosave an XML file or accept that it has been reverted to original state? Otherwise, I have to save the file again with no modification recorded.

Note that this behavior doesn't happen with other files like .java or .txt

**Update**
Here is a screenshot of the options I get to open XML files. Android Common XML Editor is currently the default editor. Text Editor is the only editor of the 3 that gives the desired behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to undo the change:

1. By manually changing the text to the original state (example: Add a space and then delete it).
2. By using Undo (<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>)

In the first case, Eclipse makes no attempt to compare the file contents to see when it might be in the original state - it just too rare and too expensive.

In the second case, Eclipse knows when all changes have been undone and will correctly remove the modified indicator.

Comment: The second phase is actually what I'm talking about. And my eclipse is not removing the modified indicator. Is there any setting that could be interfering with that?

Comment: Hm. I have never seen such a behavior before. Try to install Eclipse again without any plugins (just extract it somewhere and start it).

Comment: It seems to be happening to xml files only. I'll update the question.

Comment: I have just added a screenshot to show the ones I get. Only Text Editor works properly.

Comment: Maybe the text and Java editors have special handling. In those, Undo works :-/